# JDK 1.8.0_121\jre crashes with EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Tags: processing, graphics2d, drivers, jvm-hotspot, unfoldingmap

**Problem Context:**
I am trying to run an (unfolding) map applet using processing library as part of my coursera assignment.However, my map applet crashes with the below error log. (A normal applet runs properly though).

**SourceCode:**

```java
 //Java utilities libraries
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    //import java.util.Collections;
    //import java.util.Comparator;
    import java.util.List;
    import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.*;
    import parsing.ParseFeed;
    import processing.core.PApplet;

  public class EarthquakeCityMap extends PApplet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final boolean offline = true;

        // Less than this threshold is a light earthquake
        public static final float THRESHOLD_MODERATE = 5;
        // Less than this threshold is a minor earthquake
        public static final float THRESHOLD_LIGHT = 4;

        /** This is where to find the local tiles, for working without an Internet connection */
        public static String mbTilesString = "blankLight-1-3.mbtiles";

        // The map
        private UnfoldingMap map;

        //feed with magnitude 2.5+ Earthquakes
        private String earthquakesURL = "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/2.5_week.atom";


        public void setup() {
            size(950, 600, OPENGL);
            if (offline) {
                map = new UnfoldingMap(this, 200, 50, 700, 500, new MBTilesMapProvider(mbTilesString));
                earthquakesURL = "2.5_week.atom";   // Same feed, saved Aug 7, 2015, for working offline
            }
            else {
                map = new UnfoldingMap(this, 200, 50, 700, 500, new Microsoft.HybridProvider());
                // IF YOU WANT TO TEST WITH A LOCAL FILE, uncomment the next line
                //earthquakesURL = "2.5_week.atom";
            }       
            map.zoomToLevel(2);
            MapUtils.createDefaultEventDispatcher(this, map);   

            // The List you will populate with new SimplePointMarkers
            List<Marker> markers = new ArrayList<Marker>();

            //Use provided parser to collect properties for each earthquake
            //PointFeatures have a getLocation method
            List<PointFeature> earthquakes = ParseFeed.parseEarthquake(this, earthquakesURL);
            int yellow = color(255, 255, 0);
            int blue=color(0,255,0);
            int red=color(255,0,0);
            //TODO: Add code here as appropriate
            for (PointFeature pointFeature : earthquakes) {
                System.out.println("!$!$ pointFeature =" + pointFeature.getLocation() + " @#$#@ magnitude ="
                        + pointFeature.getProperty("magnitude"));
                markers.add(createMarker(pointFeature));
            }
            SimplePointMarker smp = null;
            float magnitude=0;
            List<Marker> updatedMarkers = new ArrayList<Marker>();
map.addMarkers(updatedMarkers);
        }

    private SimplePointMarker createMarker(PointFeature feature)
        {
            // finish implementing and use this method, if it helps.
            return new SimplePointMarker(feature.getLocation(),feature.getProperties());
        }

        public void draw() {
            background(10);
            map.draw();
            addKey();
        }

    }
```

**The full error log**

```java
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000006677b68f, pid=8856, tid=0x00000000000023d4
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_121-b13) (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.121-b13 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [aticfx64.dll+0x2b68f]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x000000005d470800):  JavaThread "Animation Thread-SharedResourceRunner" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=9172, stack(0x000000005e500000,0x000000005e600000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x0000000000000130

Top of Stack: (sp=0x000000005e5f2960)
0x000000005e5f2960:   0000000000000003 00000000564412f0
0x000000005e5f2970:   00000000564412f0 0000000000000000
0x000000005e5f2980:   0000000000000000 00000000667782d9
0x000000005e5f2990:   0000000040000e80 00000000564412f0
0x000000005e5f29a0:   000000005e5f77a8 000000005e5f3770
0x000000005e5f29b0:   000000005e5f29e0 0000000000000960
0x000000005e5f29c0:   000000005e5f29c8 0000000040000e80
0x000000005e5f29d0:   000000005e5f29e0 0000000000000960
0x000000005e5f29e0:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000005e5f29f0:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000005e5f2a00:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000005e5f2a10:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000005e5f2a20:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000005e5f2a30:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000005e5f2a40:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000005e5f2a50:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000 

Instructions: (pc=0x000000006677b68f)
0x000000006677b66f:   15 c4 5b 02 00 48 8b f8 48 85 c0 74 70 48 8b 4e
0x000000006677b67f:   20 8b 56 14 48 8d 05 a6 3c 05 00 48 89 5c 24 38
0x000000006677b68f:   8b 99 30 01 00 00 48 89 77 10 48 89 07 89 57 08
0x000000006677b69f:   48 8b 46 20 8b 88 3c 01 00 00 33 f6 89 4f 6c 48 


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x00000000667cf330 is an unknown value
RBX=0x00000000564412f0 is an unknown value
RCX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RDX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RSP=0x000000005e5f2960 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000005d470800
RBP=0x000000005e5f3770 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000005d470800
RSI=0x00000000564412f0 is an unknown value
RDI=0x00000000564453e0 is an unknown value
R8 =0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R9 =0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R10=0x0000000080000000 is an unknown value
R11=0x00000000000001b3 is an unknown value
R12=0x000000005e650180 is an unknown value
R13=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R14=0x000000006a030330 is an unknown value
R15=0x000000005e643448 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x000000005e500000,0x000000005e600000],  sp=0x000000005e5f2960,  free space=970k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [aticfx64.dll+0x2b68f]
C  [aticfx64.dll+0x282d9]
C  [atig6txx.dll+0x1f0a]
C  [atio6axx.dll+0x50942]
C  [atio6axx.dll+0xcfb06]
C  [atio6axx.dll+0x9a0f1]
C  [atio6axx.dll+0x1bb67c]
C  [atio6axx.dll+0x5b73f]
C  [atio6axx.dll+0x5989c]
C  [atio6axx.dll+0xd268]
C  [atio6axx.dll+0xc639]
C  [opengl32.dll+0x27cc0]
C  [opengl32.dll+0x27f93]
C  [opengl32.dll+0x3a976]
C  [GDI32.dll+0x39c9e]
C  0x0000000002265c74

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  jogamp.nativewindow.windows.GDI.DescribePixelFormat1(JIILjava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I+0
j  jogamp.nativewindow.windows.GDI.DescribePixelFormat(JIILjogamp/nativewindow/windows/PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR;)I+17
j  jogamp.opengl.windows.wgl.WGLUtil.DescribePixelFormat(JIILjogamp/nativewindow/windows/PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR;)I+20
j  jogamp.opengl.windows.wgl.WindowsWGLGraphicsConfiguration.wglAllGDIPFIDs(J)[I+4
j  jogamp.opengl.windows.wgl.WindowsWGLGraphicsConfigurationFactory.updateGraphicsConfigurationGDI(Ljogamp/opengl/windows/wgl/WindowsWGLGraphicsConfiguration;Ljavax/media/nativewindow/CapabilitiesChooser;JZ[I)Z+361
j  jogamp.opengl.windows.wgl.WindowsWGLGraphicsConfigurationFactory.updateGraphicsConfiguration(Ljogamp/opengl/windows/wgl/WindowsWGLGraphicsConfiguration;Ljavax/media/nativewindow/CapabilitiesChooser;Ljavax/media/opengl/GLDrawableFactory;JZ[I)V+238
j  jogamp.opengl.windows.wgl.WindowsWGLGraphicsConfigurationFactory.updateGraphicsConfiguration(Ljavax/media/nativewindow/CapabilitiesChooser;Ljavax/media/opengl/GLDrawableFactory;Ljavax/media/nativewindow/NativeSurface;[I)V+129
j  jogamp.opengl.windows.wgl.WindowsWGLGraphicsConfiguration.updateGraphicsConfiguration(Ljavax/media/opengl/GLDrawableFactory;Ljavax/media/nativewindow/NativeSurface;[I)V+7
j  jogamp.opengl.windows.wgl.WindowsWGLDrawable.setRealizedImpl()V+29
j  jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableImpl.setRealized(Z)V+197
j  jogamp.opengl.windows.wgl.WindowsWGLDrawableFactory$SharedResourceImplementation.createSharedResource(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljogamp/opengl/SharedResourceRunner$Resource;+108
j  jogamp.opengl.SharedResourceRunner.run()V+267
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
=>0x000000005d470800 JavaThread "Animation Thread-SharedResourceRunner" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=9172, stack(0x000000005e500000,0x000000005e600000)]
  0x0000000057866000 JavaThread "Animation Thread" [_thread_blocked, id=7944, stack(0x000000005c750000,0x000000005c850000)]
  0x00000000578ee800 JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-1" [_thread_blocked, id=9148, stack(0x000000005ccd0000,0x000000005cdd0000)]
  0x00000000002ff000 JavaThread "DestroyJavaVM" [_thread_blocked, id=7716, stack(0x0000000001e80000,0x0000000001f80000)]
  0x0000000057859800 JavaThread "D3D Screen Updater" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7932, stack(0x000000005b500000,0x000000005b600000)]
  0x0000000057827000 JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_blocked, id=7320, stack(0x000000005b620000,0x000000005b720000)]
  0x00000000577de800 JavaThread "thread applet-module3.EarthquakeCityMap.class" [_thread_blocked, id=8900, stack(0x000000005b400000,0x000000005b500000)]
  0x00000000577bd800 JavaThread "AWT-Windows" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=452, stack(0x0000000058160000,0x0000000058260000)]
  0x00000000577a0000 JavaThread "AWT-Shutdown" [_thread_blocked, id=1400, stack(0x0000000057f70000,0x0000000058070000)]
  0x000000005779f000 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7952, stack(0x0000000057250000,0x0000000057350000)]
  0x0000000056eab000 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4488, stack(0x0000000057510000,0x0000000057610000)]
  0x0000000056e7f000 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4404, stack(0x00000000573c0000,0x00000000574c0000)]
  0x00000000553de800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8940, stack(0x0000000056b80000,0x0000000056c80000)]
  0x00000000553d7000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8820, stack(0x0000000056d30000,0x0000000056e30000)]
  0x00000000553d2000 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8500, stack(0x00000000565a0000,0x00000000566a0000)]
  0x00000000553d1000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8432, stack(0x0000000056a50000,0x0000000056b50000)]
  0x00000000553b9800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1736, stack(0x0000000056900000,0x0000000056a00000)]
  0x0000000055372000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8380, stack(0x0000000056720000,0x0000000056820000)]

Other Threads:
  0x000000005536a800 VMThread [stack: 0x0000000056450000,0x0000000056550000] [id=8704]
  0x0000000056eb2000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x0000000057660000,0x0000000057760000] [id=7852]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap:
 PSYoungGen      total 18432K, used 16332K [0x00000000eb600000, 0x00000000eca80000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 15872K, 86% used [0x00000000eb600000,0x00000000ec37a498,0x00000000ec580000)
  from space 2560K, 98% used [0x00000000ec580000,0x00000000ec7f8b78,0x00000000ec800000)
  to   space 2560K, 0% used [0x00000000ec800000,0x00000000ec800000,0x00000000eca80000)
 ParOldGen       total 42496K, used 387K [0x00000000c2200000, 0x00000000c4b80000, 0x00000000eb600000)
  object space 42496K, 0% used [0x00000000c2200000,0x00000000c2260e90,0x00000000c4b80000)
 Metaspace       used 15802K, capacity 15985K, committed 16000K, reserved 1062912K
  class space    used 1584K, capacity 1656K, committed 1664K, reserved 1048576K

Card table byte_map: [0x0000000011610000,0x0000000011800000] byte_map_base: 0x0000000010fff000

Marking Bits: (ParMarkBitMap*) 0x000000005515b6d0
 Begin Bits: [0x0000000011f80000, 0x0000000012ef8000)
 End Bits:   [0x0000000012ef8000, 0x0000000013e70000)

Polling page: 0x0000000000100000

CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=3213Kb max_used=3221Kb free=242546Kb
 bounds [0x0000000002250000, 0x0000000002580000, 0x0000000011250000]
 total_blobs=1557 nmethods=729 adapters=742
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 16.553 Thread 0x00000000553de800  725       4       java.util.StringTokenizer::scanToken (179 bytes)
Event: 16.583 Thread 0x00000000553de800 nmethod 725 0x0000000002571b50 code [0x0000000002571ca0, 0x0000000002571f78]
Event: 16.652 Thread 0x00000000553d7000  726   !   4       java.lang.SecurityManager::checkPackageAccess (156 bytes)
Event: 17.001 Thread 0x00000000553d7000 nmethod 726 0x00000000025753d0 code [0x0000000002575600, 0x0000000002577050]
Event: 17.088 Thread 0x0000000056e7f000  727       1       java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder::implReset (1 bytes)
Event: 17.089 Thread 0x0000000056e7f000 nmethod 727 0x0000000002570e50 code [0x0000000002570fa0, 0x00000000025710b0]
Event: 17.403 Thread 0x0000000056e7f000  728       3       java.util.ArrayList::toArray (60 bytes)
Event: 17.405 Thread 0x0000000056e7f000 nmethod 728 0x00000000025703d0 code [0x0000000002570560, 0x0000000002570af8]
Event: 17.441 Thread 0x0000000056e7f000  729       3       java.lang.ClassLoader::compareCerts (149 bytes)
Event: 17.445 Thread 0x0000000056e7f000 nmethod 729 0x000000000256f490 code [0x000000000256f660, 0x000000000256fef8]

GC Heap History (2 events):
Event: 5.897 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=1 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 18432K, used 15872K [0x00000000eb600000, 0x00000000eca80000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 15872K, 100% used [0x00000000eb600000,0x00000000ec580000,0x00000000ec580000)
  from space 2560K, 0% used [0x00000000ec800000,0x00000000ec800000,0x00000000eca80000)
  to   space 2560K, 0% used [0x00000000ec580000,0x00000000ec580000,0x00000000ec800000)
 ParOldGen       total 42496K, used 0K [0x00000000c2200000, 0x00000000c4b80000, 0x00000000eb600000)
  object space 42496K, 0% used [0x00000000c2200000,0x00000000c2200000,0x00000000c4b80000)
 Metaspace       used 11045K, capacity 11198K, committed 11264K, reserved 1058816K
  class space    used 1212K, capacity 1278K, committed 1280K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 5.925 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=1 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 18432K, used 2530K [0x00000000eb600000, 0x00000000eca80000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 15872K, 0% used [0x00000000eb600000,0x00000000eb600000,0x00000000ec580000)
  from space 2560K, 98% used [0x00000000ec580000,0x00000000ec7f8b78,0x00000000ec800000)
  to   space 2560K, 0% used [0x00000000ec800000,0x00000000ec800000,0x00000000eca80000)
 ParOldGen       total 42496K, used 387K [0x00000000c2200000, 0x00000000c4b80000, 0x00000000eb600000)
  object space 42496K, 0% used [0x00000000c2200000,0x00000000c2260e90,0x00000000c4b80000)
 Metaspace       used 11045K, capacity 11198K, committed 11264K, reserved 1058816K
  class space    used 1212K, capacity 1278K, committed 1280K, reserved 1048576K
}

Deoptimization events (3 events):
Event: 6.010 Thread 0x0000000057866000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000002482c18 method=java.io.WinNTFileSystem.normalize(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String; @ 128
Event: 6.079 Thread 0x0000000057866000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00000000024373fc method=java.lang.String.indexOf([CII[CIII)I @ 3
Event: 16.438 Thread 0x0000000057866000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000002419abc method=java.lang.String.startsWith(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z @ 25

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 0.304 Thread 0x00000000002ff000 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError': Method sun.misc.Unsafe.prefetchRead(Ljava/lang/Object;J)V name or signature does not match> (0x00000000eb607f90) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u121\8372\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims
Event: 0.954 Thread 0x00000000002ff000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000eb67a6e8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u121\8372\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1390]
Event: 0.954 Thread 0x00000000002ff000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000eb67a8f8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u121\8372\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1390]
Event: 0.959 Thread 0x00000000002ff000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000eb67e808) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u121\8372\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1390]
Event: 0.960 Thread 0x00000000002ff000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000eb67ea18) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u121\8372\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1390]
Event: 1.156 Thread 0x00000000002ff000 Exception <a 'java/io/FileNotFoundException'> (0x00000000eb69d638) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u121\8372\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 709]
Event: 1.527 Thread 0x00000000002ff000 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchFieldError': method resolution failed> (0x00000000eb7bb418) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u121\8372\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\methodHandles.cpp, line 1146]
Event: 1.546 Thread 0x00000000002ff000 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchFieldError': method resolution failed> (0x00000000eb7c87e8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u121\8372\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\methodHandles.cpp, line 1146]
Event: 2.001 Thread 0x00000000002ff000 Exception <a 'java/io/FileNotFoundException'> (0x00000000eb895c70) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u121\8372\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 709]
Event: 2.822 Thread 0x00000000002ff000 Exception <a 'java/io/FileNotFoundException'> (0x00000000eb8c1b90) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u121\8372\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 709]

Events (10 events):
Event: 17.099 loading class com/jogamp/nativewindow/UpstreamSurfaceHookMutableSize
Event: 17.099 loading class com/jogamp/nativewindow/UpstreamSurfaceHookMutableSize done
Event: 17.103 loading class javax/media/nativewindow/UpstreamSurfaceHook$MutableSize
Event: 17.103 loading class javax/media/nativewindow/UpstreamSurfaceHook$MutableSize done
Event: 17.113 loading class jogamp/nativewindow/SurfaceUpdatedHelper
Event: 17.113 loading class jogamp/nativewindow/SurfaceUpdatedHelper done
Event: 17.385 loading class jogamp/nativewindow/windows/RegisteredClass
Event: 17.386 loading class jogamp/nativewindow/windows/RegisteredClass done
Event: 17.432 loading class jogamp/opengl/windows/wgl/WGLUtil
Event: 17.432 loading class jogamp/opengl/windows/wgl/WGLUtil done


Dynamic libraries:
0x000000013f020000 - 0x000000013f057000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\bin\javaw.exe
0x0000000076d80000 - 0x0000000076f2a000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x0000000076b60000 - 0x0000000076c7f000     C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
0x000007fefcbe0000 - 0x000007fefcc4a000     C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x000007fefd390000 - 0x000007fefd46b000     C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x000007fefd160000 - 0x000007fefd1ff000     C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x000007fefec70000 - 0x000007fefec8f000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
0x000007fefe6d0000 - 0x000007fefe7fd000     C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x0000000076c80000 - 0x0000000076d7a000     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
0x000007fefe800000 - 0x000007fefe867000     C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
0x000007fefec60000 - 0x000007fefec6e000     C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll
0x000007fefd090000 - 0x000007fefd15a000     C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll
0x000007fefb670000 - 0x000007fefb864000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.18837_none_fa3b1e3d17594757\COMCTL32.dll
0x000007fefebe0000 - 0x000007fefec51000     C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x000007fefe600000 - 0x000007fefe62e000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x000007fefead0000 - 0x000007fefebd9000     C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x00000000667f0000 - 0x00000000668c2000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x0000000054940000 - 0x00000000551db000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x000007fef95a0000 - 0x000007fef95a9000     C:\Windows\system32\WSOCK32.dll
0x000007fefef60000 - 0x000007fefefad000     C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x000007fefd470000 - 0x000007fefd478000     C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
0x000007fefad60000 - 0x000007fefad9b000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x000007fefbb60000 - 0x000007fefbb6c000     C:\Windows\system32\VERSION.dll
0x0000000076f50000 - 0x0000000076f57000     C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x0000000068750000 - 0x000000006875f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x0000000067780000 - 0x00000000677a9000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\bin\java.dll
0x0000000068730000 - 0x0000000068746000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x000007fefd870000 - 0x000007fefe5f9000     C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
0x000007fefce80000 - 0x000007fefd083000     C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
0x000007fefcac0000 - 0x000007fefcacf000     C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
0x00000000595e0000 - 0x0000000059778000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\bin\awt.dll
0x000007fefefb0000 - 0x000007feff08a000     C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x000007fefab70000 - 0x000007fefab88000     C:\Windows\system32\DWMAPI.DLL
0x000007fee8320000 - 0x000007fee843d000     C:\Windows\system32\opengl32.dll
0x000007feee880000 - 0x000007feee8ad000     C:\Windows\system32\GLU32.dll
0x000007fee8040000 - 0x000007fee8131000     C:\Windows\system32\DDRAW.dll
0x000007fefb640000 - 0x000007fefb648000     C:\Windows\system32\DCIMAN32.dll
0x000007fefe870000 - 0x000007fefea47000     C:\Windows\system32\SETUPAPI.dll
0x000007fefce00000 - 0x000007fefce36000     C:\Windows\system32\CFGMGR32.dll
0x000007fefcae0000 - 0x000007fefcafa000     C:\Windows\system32\DEVOBJ.dll
0x000007fefb2f0000 - 0x000007fefb346000     C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x000007fefc960000 - 0x000007fefc96f000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x000007fee6a00000 - 0x000007fee6bff000     C:\Windows\system32\d3d9.dll
0x000007feefa00000 - 0x000007feefa07000     C:\Windows\system32\d3d8thk.dll
0x0000000058460000 - 0x00000000588df000     C:\Windows\system32\atiumd64.dll
0x0000000058a10000 - 0x0000000058ca4000     C:\Windows\system32\atiumd6a.dll
0x0000000067520000 - 0x0000000067567000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\bin\fontmanager.dll
0x0000000067500000 - 0x000000006751a000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\bin\net.dll
0x000007fefc250000 - 0x000007fefc2a5000     C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
0x000007fefc390000 - 0x000007fefc397000     C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll
0x00000000674e0000 - 0x00000000674f1000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\bin\nio.dll
0x0000000067490000 - 0x00000000674d2000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\bin\t2k.dll
0x000007fefc2b0000 - 0x000007fefc2c8000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
0x000007fefbfc0000 - 0x000007fefc007000     C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x000007fefcbc0000 - 0x000007fefcbde000     C:\Windows\system32\USERENV.dll
0x000007fefa840000 - 0x000007fefa867000     C:\Windows\system32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
0x000007fefa830000 - 0x000007fefa83b000     C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
0x000007fef9da0000 - 0x000007fef9db8000     C:\Windows\system32\dhcpcsvc.DLL
0x000007fef9c80000 - 0x000007fef9c91000     C:\Windows\system32\dhcpcsvc6.DLL
0x000007fefc8c0000 - 0x000007fefc917000     C:\Windows\system32\apphelp.dll
0x00000000637c0000 - 0x00000000637cd000     C:\Users\mulshankar13\AppData\Local\Temp\jogamp_0000\file_cache\jln644846991770280656\jln8614955928550457044\gluegen-rt.dll
0x00000000687d0000 - 0x00000000687d7000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\bin\jawt.dll
0x000000006a440000 - 0x000000006a44d000     C:\Users\mulshankar13\AppData\Local\Temp\jogamp_0000\file_cache\jln644846991770280656\jln8614955928550457044\nativewindow_awt.dll
0x000000006c100000 - 0x000000006c10f000     C:\Users\mulshankar13\AppData\Local\Temp\jogamp_0000\file_cache\jln644846991770280656\jln8614955928550457044\nativewindow_win32.dll
0x0000000064500000 - 0x00000000645a2000     C:\Users\mulshankar13\AppData\Local\Temp\jogamp_0000\file_cache\jln644846991770280656\jln8614955928550457044\jogl_desktop.dll
0x0000000069030000 - 0x000000006a12d000     C:\Windows\system32\atio6axx.dll
0x000007feee8b0000 - 0x000007feee8b9000     C:\Windows\system32\atig6txx.dll
0x0000000066750000 - 0x00000000667e6000     C:\Windows\system32\aticfx64.dll
0x0000000180000000 - 0x0000000180050000     C:\Windows\system32\atiadlxx.dll
0x000007fefce40000 - 0x000007fefce7b000     C:\Windows\system32\WINTRUST.dll
0x000007fefcc80000 - 0x000007fefcded000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPT32.dll
0x000007fefcad0000 - 0x000007fefcadf000     C:\Windows\system32\MSASN1.dll
0x000007fef5d00000 - 0x000007fef5e25000     C:\Windows\system32\dbghelp.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Djava.security.policy=java.policy.applet -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 
java_command: sun.applet.AppletViewer module3.EarthquakeCityMap1492253849718.html
java_class_path (initial): E:\_graphWorkspace\UCSDUnfoldingMaps\build;E:\_graphWorkspace\UCSDUnfoldingMaps\lib\core.jar;E:\_graphWorkspace\UCSDUnfoldingMaps\lib\gluegen-rt.jar;E:\_graphWorkspace\UCSDUnfoldingMaps\lib\jogl-all.jar;E:\_graphWorkspace\UCSDUnfoldingMaps\lib\log4j-1.2.15.jar;E:\_graphWorkspace\UCSDUnfoldingMaps\lib\sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar;E:\_graphWorkspace\UCSDUnfoldingMaps\lib\json4processing.jar;E:\_graphWorkspace\UCSDUnfoldingMaps\lib\libTUIO.jar;E:\_graphWorkspace\UCSDUnfoldingMaps\lib\unfolding.0.9.7-uscd.jar
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60
JRE_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre
PATH=C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_121/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_121/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_121/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Dell\Dell Wireless WLAN Card;c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;E:\eclipse-jee-neon-R-win32-x86_64\eclipse;
---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 7 , 64 bit Build 7601 (6.1.7601.23539)

CPU:total 4 (2 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 37 stepping 2, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, ht, tsc, tscinvbit

Memory: 4k page, physical 4051480k(869292k free), swap 8101100k(3814264k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.121-b13) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_121-b13), built on Dec 12 2016 18:21:36 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 10.0 (VS2010)
```

**Research and solutions tried out**
I found these similar posts in SO [JVM crashing EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) :problematic frame in jvmti agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43305245/jvm-crashing-exception-access-violation-0xc0000005-problematic-frame-in-jvmti) and [Possible causes of Java VM EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140030/possible-causes-of-java-vm-exception-access-violation) and [Upgrade to latest Oracle JDK 1.8.0_121-b13 loses PBEWithMD5AndDES Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41839060/upgrade-to-latest-oracle-jdk-1-8-0-121-b13-loses-pbewithmd5anddes-algorithm). But it did not solve my problem.
I have uninstalled Java 1.8 twice and reinstalled it only to find the problem still there. Another event that I must mention is I have recently updated my graphics driver from DELL after which this problem has happened (coincidentally).
Any advise would be great meanwhile I have already reported this to http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp

Comment: What are you running this? Are you really running this as an applet? Can you run other applications? Can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: @KevinWorkman added the source code as well

Comment: I'm not trying to be annoying, but can you try to isolate the problem to the **minimal** piece of code that causes the error? Can you run a Processing sketch without the map stuff? Which line of code causes the problem?

Comment: @KevinWorkman I am sorry Kevin. Tried breaking the problem into smaller pieces and these were the findings. This program is part of an assignment in coursera on OO Programming in Java where we are trying to display some earthquake data on a map provided by Google (or Mircosoft or OpenStreet). 
The problem is with this line size(950, 600, OPENGL); When I change this line to size(950,600); it works fine with both the offline mode (where it connects to a local tiles provider) and online mode (where it connects to any of the major map providers as Google/Microsoft).The problem is with 
OpenGL.

Comment: I might now submit a fresh crash report to http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp

Comment: You might want to edit the example code you're using so it's just a basic sketch that calls the `size()` function and uses an argument of `OPENGL`, that way it's more obvious what's happening. But honestly this doesn't sound like a Java bug. It sounds like an issue with your graphics card. That also makes it next to impossible for us to help you debug.

Comment: I agree with Kevin Workman, it might be caused by a regression in your OpenGL graphics driver and you can probably reproduce your bug with a rudimentary example based on JOGL.

Comment: @gouessej correct! I'll update my answer once i m back handling this problem as something else is occupying my time